# Pyspark 1.6.3 error when trying to use to_date method

Tags: python, dataframe, date, pyspark

im currently working on pyspark 1.6.3 and there is this error. Do you know what can be the reason?

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBDwh.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pyspark 1.6 version to_date has only one argument from version it is accepting 2 parameters
For 1.6:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions

For 2.3:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions